# Wrong category in URLs accepted like the correct one

Tags: categories, permalinks

When we type in `https://example.com/2019/07/22/news/midcoast/regulate-group-homes-in-residential-neighborhoods/` we can of course view the intended article.

Then when I change the category names to anything at all for example, `https://example.com/2019/07/22/news/nonexistentcategory/regulate-group-homes-in-residential-neighborhoods/` it will continue to bring up the correct article, but the behavior should be that it redirects to the correct category name.

We think this may have been some custom that the previous developer created, but have been unable to track it down. Our thought was that is a some rewrite canonical function. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is unfortunately a built-in behavior in WordPress.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts regarding how to change this behavior?